# Mac Os X - Change display name of Today View/Widget in notification center

Tags: macos, widget, rename, notificationcenter

So im making an app extension and my main app is called inTime, but when i created my extension it wouldnt let me have the same file name for obvious reasons. So i called it inTime Extension. Now i want to make notification center display inTime instead of inTime extension! Ill post a screenshot to make it clearer!

https://gyazo.com/aedb5fdcd113d1c13a4e118a9931ed15
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

See InfoPlist.strings File, which should be created automatically.
Change "CFBundleDisplayName" = "TO YOUR NAME";